# Concatenate is not being used

Tags: java

I have a simple method where the goal is to add "[" and "]" before and after every "."

For example:

Input: address = "1.1.1.1"
Output: "1[.]1[.]1[.]1"

Here is the function I've written, the problem here is where I have concatenate, why is this happening?

```
public static String defangIPaddr(String address) {
   String returnStr = "";
   for(int i = 0; i < address.length(); i++) {
       char c = address.charAt(i);
       if(c == '.') {
           returnStr.concat("[");       
           returnStr.concat("."); 
           returnStr.concat("]");                               
        } else {
           returnStr.concat(address);
        }
    }           
   return returnStr;       
}
```

Comment: you've used concat, but you've missed preserving, how about `returnStr = returnStr.concat(c == "." ? "[.]" : c);`?       `

Comment: `concat` does not alter the String in place, because Strings are immutable. It returns a new String, but you never reassign that value back to `returnStr`, so the result is lost

Comment: You also presumably mean `returnStr.concat("" + c)`, rather than `returnStr.concat(address)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `replace()` instead, just like this:

```
public static String defangIPaddr(String address) {
    return address.replace(".", "[.]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been explained, `concat` doesn't change the string, but rather returns a new string which is the concatenation of the two strings.

```
returnStr = returnStr.concat("[");
```

However, don't use `concat`. You rarely (if ever) need to use this. Instead use `+=`:

```
returnStr += "[";
```

But you don't even really want to use this, because it inefficiently creates a new string every time you do this. That's fine if the concatenation is a one-off, but you don't want to do this in a loop.

Use a `StringBuilder` instead, which allows you to append to the string without creating a new object each time:

```
String returnStr = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < address.length(); i++) {
   // ...
   returnStr.append("[");
   // ...
}
return returnStr.toString();
```

Or, of course, in this simple case, use `replace`.